# R dplyr fill fails to populate data in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am filling in the columns by group but it doesn't work as expected. My goal is to fill dates and then compare dates in each row and find the oldest date.

```
mydata<-
structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), inst = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "rectr"), instance = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), A_returne = c("", "2019-11-07", 
"2019-11-08", "2019-11-07", "", ""), B_date = c("2018-10-29", 
"", "", "", "2018-11-27", ""), C_returned_date = c("2018-11-10", 
"", "", "", "2018-12-12", ""), D_returned_date = c("2021-05-21", 
"", "", "", "", ""), A_ordered = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "2021-01-14"), B_received = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "2021-02-17")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

mycode:
mydata %>%
group_by(record_id) %>%
fill(A_returne,C_returned_date,D_returned_date, .direction ="downup")
```

Comment: Fwiw fill() is from tidyr, not dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your data contains blank strings and not missing `NA` values.

Replace the "" values with NA and it should work.

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) na_if(x, ""))) %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  fill(A_returne,C_returned_date,D_returned_date, .direction ="downup")
# A tibble: 6 × 9
# Groups:   record_id [5]
  record_id inst  instance A_returne  B_date     C_returned_date D_returned_date A_ordered  B_received
      <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <chr>           <chr>      <chr>     
1         1 NA          NA NA         2018-10-29 2018-11-10      2021-05-21      NA         NA        
2         2 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA        
3         3 NA          NA 2019-11-08 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA        
4         4 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA        
5         5 NA          NA NA         2018-11-27 2018-12-12      NA              NA         NA        
6         5 rectr        1 NA         NA         2018-12-12      NA              2021-01-14 2021-02-17
```

The only difference here is that C_returned_date is now filled for record id 5.

It depends on what your expected output is but you can fill all the missing values by just omitting the `group_by()` line.

### Edit

In response to the newly added question, to find the oldest date per row you can use `pmin()`.

```
res <- mydata %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) na_if(x, ""))) %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  fill(A_returne,C_returned_date,D_returned_date, .direction ="downup")

res %>%
  mutate(oldest_date = pmin(A_returne,C_returned_date,D_returned_date, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 6 × 10
# Groups:   record_id [5]
  record_id inst  instance A_returne  B_date     C_returned_date D_returned_date A_ordered  B_received oldest_date
      <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      
1         1 NA          NA NA         2018-10-29 2018-11-10      2021-05-21      NA         NA         2018-11-10 
2         2 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         2019-11-07 
3         3 NA          NA 2019-11-08 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         2019-11-08 
4         4 NA          NA 2019-11-07 NA         NA              NA              NA         NA         2019-11-07 
5         5 NA          NA NA         2018-11-27 2018-12-12      NA              NA         NA         2018-12-12 
6         5 rectr        1 NA         NA         2018-12-12      NA              2021-01-14 2021-02-17 2018-12-12
```

Comment: for record 1 why is 2018-10-29 be the oldest date? Also, is there a way to assign a value "1" to a new column res$A if the oldest date is found is columns A_returne ,B_date ,C_returned_date and assign a value "1" to a new column res$B is the oldest date is found in columns A_ordered ,B_received

Comment: Which columns are you looking at specifically when searching for the earliest date?

Comment: Oh, i noticed you did not have the column included the the search. So your result is correct! Thanks!